# google analytics plugin doesn't work in kettle with firewall

Tags: google-analytics-api, kettle

I'm using Google Analytics plugin for kettle. And it gives me this error:

com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Error connecting with login URI
2013/09/12 12:38:17 - Google Analytics 2.0 - ERROR (version 3.2.0-GA, build 10572 from 2009-05-12 08.45.26 by buildguy) : Error connecting with login URI

I'm working in a lan with firewall, but i can acces without problems to the url of google analytics. I've been searching about the ports that Google Aanlytics uses, and I found that 80 http and 443 for https.

So now, I think that isn't a port problem....

Please, could anybody help me??

Thanks in advance!